# Why can't you change characters using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

recently I got a copy of the C Programming Language Book.
On page 95 there is an implementation of the strcpy function.

```
void strcopy(char *s, char *t) {
    while(*s++ = *t++) 
        ;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *hello = "hello";
    char *world = "world";

    strcopy(hello, world);
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to implement it myself, but after (successfully) compiling with

```
gcc -o c_lang c_programming_lang_exercises.c
```

and trying running it with

```
./c_lang
```

I get the following error message:

```
zsh: bus error
```

I tried it with different implementations, but somehow this does not work for me.

Maybe someone has an idea why?

Thank you for your help :)

---

Edit:
For my own understanding, please correct me if im wrong.
In the function call "strcopy(hello, world);" i pass the value of the pointers itself here, so i call the function with something like this: strcopy(0x123a4, 0x234859b). Now C doesnt sees this as variable, and therefore its value get copied and passed to the function.
In the strcopy function itself i cant dereference it, because i just get the value of the pointers.

What i should do is to pass the address, the pointers refere to, so that i can dereference the values in the strcopy function and access the right memory address.

The other mistake was probably in the main function i declared `char *hello = "hello"`that is as far as I understand it, called a string constant and is therefore not modifiable.

So, if my assumptions are correct, the following code should work:

```
void strcopy(char *s, char *t) {
    //code goes here...
}
int main(int stringc, char *argv[]) {
    char hello[] = "hello";
    char world[] = "world";
    strcopy(&hello, &world);
    return 0;
}
```

And it works, but i get the following compiler warning:

```
 incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[6]' to parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    strcopy(&hello, &world);
```

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function in your code.

Comment: What are you passing to `s`? A string literal? Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: Also note the code you have posted has an extra `{`.

Comment: You should post [mcve]. The function by itself will work *if used as intended*.

Comment: Note that your function does not conform to the C standard library function of that name. For one thing, it should return the destination pointer as passed.

Comment: yup; `strcpy(hello, world);` is what you want.  The C type system is subtle and convenient.   It does not reward baroque (aka over-specifiers).  Keep specification to a minimum, understand why this is a good philosophy and you will be successful with C.  Attempt to specify the minimum.

Comment: IDK how late to the party I am, but OP has minimal example from the book he is reading. Why not explain why the posted example is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C makes a really bad concession when it comes to types, and this has to do with historical reasons.

In `main()`, you declare your strings as:

```
char *hello = "hello";
```

What you should do is turn the warning levels *waaaay* up and recompile. The problem is that `"hello"` is a string *literal* — it *cannot* be modified. It should be declared as:

```
const char *hello = "hello";
```

(Turning warnings up will tell you this.)

Consequently, you are trying to copy characters into read-only memory, which, on modern processors and with modern compilers, is not permitted — it produces an access violation. Zsh complains for you.

Instead, make sure you have write access to a local array that is copied from read-only memory:

```
char hello[] = "hello";
```

Yep, that makes a local, *mutable* array that is six characters long (five for the word “hello” plus one for the null-terminator) and automatically initialized from the read-only memory.

This is one of those subtle sticking points to declaring things in C that confuses beginners regularly:

- `const char * s = "Hello world!";` — pointer to ROM
- `char s[] = "Hello world!";` — local, mutable array initialized from ROM

That’s it!